# Segmentation fault when trying to pass dynamic array to processes

Tags: c++, mpi

I tried to pass dynamic array from 0 process to 1 and vice versa. Getting segmentation fault in process 1. All matrices printed as expected. What could be the problem in this situation?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  int n;
  cin >> n; 
  int *matrix = new int[n*n];
  int *matrix2 = new int[n*n];
  int i,j,ProcNum,ProcRank;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);
  MPI_Status status;
  if (ProcRank == 0){
    /* Filling matrices here with i*n + j values*/
    MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&(matrix[0]), n*n, MPI_INT, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&(matrix[0]), n*n, MPI_INT, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    print_matrix(matrix,n);
  }
  if (ProcRank > 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&(matrix[0]), n*n, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    /*passing i-j values to matrix and printing them here*/
    MPI_Send(&(matrix[0]), n*n, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  delete matrix;
  delete matrix2;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: In process 1, `n` with which `matrix` was allocated is not necessarily the same `n` with which `MPI_Recv` is called. You first read `n` from `cin`, allocate memory based on that value, then read possibly a different value with `MPI_Recv(&n, ...)`, and finally read the amount of data determined by the new `n` into memory allocated for the old `n`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How could we achieve equal ```n``` for each process?

Comment: First receive `n` from the other process, then allocate memory of the right size for that `n`, and then receive data into that memory. You've switched steps 1 and 2 - you allocate memory first, and determine the necessary size second.

Comment: An alternative is to pass `n` via the command line instead of reading it from `stdin`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet is there a guarantee that all processes get the commandline?

Comment: I quickly checked the standard, and at first glance, it does not address this.
FWIW, all implementations I have ever used do pass the command line to all processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive input in parallel programs is always dangerous. Your MPI processes are often started through an ssh connection, and so they will probably not get the terminal input. Process zero most likely will, so I'd advocate reading `n` only on process zero and then broadcasting it.